# CefSharp - Strongly Named

Tags: c#, browser, chromium, cefsharp

I'm getting errors when loading CefSharp assemblies in my project. Both CefSharp and CefSharp.WinForms are not strongly named. Is there any way around this?

Error:

```
Referenced assembly 'CefSharp.WinForms' does not have a strong name 
Referenced assembly 'CefSharp' does not have a strong name
```

Thanks.

Comment: Adding exact errors may help to get an answer.

Comment: What I described pretty much is the error, but I added the output above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strongly signed assemblies can't refer to non-signed assemblies. So your options are:

- find (or create if license allows you to do so) strongly signed version of the CefSharp.XXX assemblies
- stop signing your own assemblies
- use `Assembly.Load` and reflection to use non-signed assembly.